# How to display image to my listbox from my database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, listbox

The property in the database is image. What's in the content is binary data. This is the datatemplate of the listbox:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Width="467" Height="123" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <Image Name="imgProduct" Source="{Binding pImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5" Width="115"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pName}" Margin="120,0,133,92" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="22.667"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pPrice}" Margin="146,69,263,35" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13.333"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pQty}" Margin="232,30,183,76" Foreground="#FF11BB00" FontSize="13.333" FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pRewardCost}" Margin="433,89,0,14" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="#7F000000"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pSalesPrice}" Margin="155,85,233,14" Foreground="#FF005910" FontSize="17.333" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.196,0.375"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" Height="15" Width="114">
                <Run Text="Quantity Available:"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text=":"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SGD" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.923,0.625" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SGD" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="17.333" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.923,0.625"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,89,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Reward Points cost:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="#7F000000"/>
            <InkPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="2" Margin="122,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Background="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <InkPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                </InkPresenter.RenderTransform>
            </InkPresenter>
            <InkPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="2" Margin="0,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" Background="#66000000"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The C# Code that consumes the database and shows as items on the listbox is as below:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var pdtQry = from pdt in fypDB.Products
                     select pdt;


        productCollection = new DataServiceCollection<Product>();




        productCollection.LoadCompleted += new
        EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(productCollection_LoadCompleted);

        productCollection.LoadAsync(pdtQry);
    }
    void productCollection_LoadCompleted(Object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (productCollection.Continuation != null) productCollection.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
        else
        {  
            listboxSearch.ItemsSource = productCollection;


        }

    }
```

After debugging, pName, pPrice, pQty, pRewardCost, and pSalesPrice. However the image is not displayed. I think it may be because the image is not of the same format. The format in dbo is image and is `<binary data>`. Is there any way to convert and display it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well formed first question !! Good Start.

Comment: what is DataType for Product.pImage ?

Comment: In WPF it should work out of the box if `pImage` is a `byte[]` that contains an encoded image buffer, e.g. a JPEG. However, in Windows Phone you may have to use a binding converter that creates a `BitmapImage` from the byte array. Note that Windows Phone is not WPF.

Comment: @Muds The Data type is "Image". when I view the data, it's binary data.

Comment: @Clemens I've removed the WPF tag. I'm new to programming, may I know how to create a binding converter?

Comment: a simple tutorial can b found [here](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Comment: I used a converter, but when I debugged, an InvalidCastException in 
byte[] pImage = (byte[])value;
and
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);

Comment: Than `pImage` is obviously not of type `byte[]`. What type is it? Please provide the fully qualified type name, as `Image` could be quite a lot.

Comment: @Clemens The name is pImage. Data Type is image. Identity Increment and Identity Seed = 0. Length =2147483647. When I view the table Data, I see <Binary Data>. Is the type Binary? What is the codes to for the value converter for this?

Comment: I've tried this:
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage pImage = new BitmapImage();
            pImage.SetSource(memStream);
            return pImage;
        }

Comment: Then:
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Comment: We already know that the name of the property is `pImage`. And `image` is not a fully qualified type name. What is its namespace? If you aren't able to find it out, I'd recommend to get back to your favourite C# book and read up on language basics.

Comment: Please stop posting code in comments. Nobody is able to read that. You may edit your question.

Comment: @YouHongHappyzhi The type Image you mentioned is type of SQL column that is holding image data, I guess. What is the type of C# property Product.pImage? It should not be Image as that will simply not work.